# 認証プロキシ環境下でのgradleの使用

Tags: cordova, gradle

Cordovaプロジェクトでandroid向けにビルドする際に以下のようなエラーが発生し、ビルドが成功しません。

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy.
Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required
```

Gradleのプロキシの設定として、`Users/<user-name>/.gradle/gradle.properties`には以下のような設定をしています。

```
systemProp.http.proxyUser= *User*
systemProp.http.proxyPassword= *password*
systemProp.http.proxyHost= *host*
systemProp.http.proxyPort= 8080
systemProp.https.proxyUser= *User*
systemProp.https.proxyPassword= *password*
systemProp.https.proxyHost= *host*
systemProp.https.proxyPort= 8080
systemProp.jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
```

他に何か認証に失敗する要因がありましたら教えていただけないでしょうか。

追記、
gradlewには以下のオプションを追加しています。

```
# Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and GRADLE_OPTS to pass JVM options to this script.  

DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=\"\""
```

Comment: `systemProp.https.proxyUser` の設定が見当たりませんが、記載漏れで実際には設定されている、という事でよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。すみません記入漏れです。該当の項目は記入しています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

これ（`jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""`）ではないですかね？

https://qiita.com/kaakaa_hoe/items/d4fb11a3af035a287972

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
今試してみたのですが、やはりうまくいかないようです。  

gradlewに以下を追記しました。
# Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and GRADLE_OPTS to pass JVM options to this script.
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=\"\""

Comment: `systemProp.jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""`を`gradle.properties`に追加したら、どうなりますか？

Comment: 確かにそこに追加していませんでした。
追加してみましたが、うまくいかず、同じエラーが出力されています。

Comment: 例外のスタックトレースは出力されていますか？

Comment: 一度、gradle関係の物をすべて削除し、再度インストールしたうえで、教えていただいた設定をしたところ407は出力されなくなりました。ありがとうございます。